# Retrieving row data from jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

```
    var rowdata;
        var records = $("#tblWorkGroupDetails").getGridParam("reccount");
        for (var i = 0; i < records; i++) {
            var index = i;
            var rowId = jQuery('#tblWorkGroupDetails tr:eq(' + index + ')').attr('id');
            rowdata = $('#tblWorkGroupDetails').getCell(rowId, 'groupname') + "," + $('#tblWorkGroupDetails').getCell(rowId, 'workcode');
        }
```

Am getting rowdata as 'false,false'. Anyone?

Comment: Okay, so the 'groupname' here must be the same as the 'name' attribute set in colModel. I was taking the 'index' attribute instead.

Comment: You can answer your questions on Stack Overflow and even accept them after a while.

Comment: Of course I didn't mean that. I found out the issue after posting the question here. Thought it would be helpful for others as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.length` for `records`

like,

```
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var index = i;
    var rowId = jQuery('#tblWorkGroupDetails tr:eq(' + index + ')').attr('id');
    rowdata = $('#tblWorkGroupDetails').getCell(rowId, 'groupname') + "," + $('#tblWorkGroupDetails').getCell(rowId, 'workcode');
}
```

**Also,** check what value comes in `rowId`.

Comment: Am already getting the row count in records, as mentioned above. It seems to serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowData = $("#tblWorkGroupDetails").jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);

    to access each column value say,
    rowData.name
```